# What is the best way to monitor elastic apm server with Prometheus?

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus, monitoring, elastic-apm

would be great if somebody can help and suggest me the best way to have **elastic apm server monitored with Prometheus**.

From elastic documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/guide/current/monitor-apm.html I see they suggest metricbeat to pickup metrics and send it to elasticsearch, but I am wondering if there is any way of doing this with some kind of exporter, that will export metrics from apm server to Prometheus.

Happy to hear any suggestions and/or hints on this topic!